# Where I can find the code of ASP.NET Web Api Beta version?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

For troubleshooting I want to take a look and debug into the code of asp.net web api, I guess it is from here:

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/

But cannot find the branch for web api code version BETA integrate with MVC 4 beta, the up-to-date code is different with beta version

Edit: MVC 4 RC has just been released, seem I need to find the code of MVC 4 RC as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately we didn't actually create a branch for the beta -- we started with that in RC. Yes, there are changes (see here [0]) -- you can find some information about how to go about them at [1]. There is also a description of the RC NuGet packages here [2]

Thanks,

Henrik

[0] http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2012/06/aspnet-web-api-changes-from-beta-to-rc.html

[1] http://kamranicus.com/Blog/Posts/48/tips-for-updating-from-webapi-beta-to-webapi-rc

[2] http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/06/01/asp-net-mvc-web-api-and-web-pages-nuget-packages.aspx